# Terraform: Error opening S3 bucket object source

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm new to Terraform and when trying to create an S3 static website bucket using modules, getting the below error:

```
Error: Error opening S3 bucket object source (index.html): open index.html: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is my folder structure:

- Terraform

  - My-Module

    - main.tf
    - index.html
  - Use-My-Module

    - c1-main.tf

Here's the code in my Terraform > My-Module > main.tf :

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
  bucket = "tf-static-web-test"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "bucket-acl" {
  acl = "public-read"
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  policy = "..."
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  content_type = "text/html"
  key = "index.html"
  source = "index.html"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "website" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }
  error_document {
    key = "error.html"
  }
}
```

The code in Terraform > Use-My-Module > c1-main.tf is :

```
module "my_static_website" {
  source = "../My-Module"
}
```

I have another file also with provider information and Terraform block in this same location.

Please help me with this error.

Comment: What about doing `source = "${path.module}/index.html"`?

Comment: Above solution worked, thanks dude.